# Laravel join 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have some issues with joining 2 tables at one table with Laravel.
So I want to create some tipe of forum and, so far I have Categories, Threads and Posts.
So category model should get last item of threads or posts, that is posted most recently.
So query should check all threads and last posts and retrieve the latest one.
So here is what I did in Category model:

```
self::where('id', $this->id)
            ->join('forum_threads', 'forum_categories.id', '=', 'forum_threads.category_id')
            ->leftJoin('forum_posts', 'forum_threads.id', '=', 'forum_posts.thread_id')
            ->select(['forum_posts.*', 'forum_threads.*'])
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

But this don't do what I need to, I can't get threads and posts in one resource and order them so I could get latest ones. Any ideas?

Comment: ```orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');```

Comment: Please read the question :)

Comment: Do you not have relationships set up between these models? That's a huge part of the reason to use Laravel; so you don't have to worry about your database structure and do things like `$this->latestPost()->with("threads")->get()`

Answer (score 0):

$this->latestPost()->with("threads")->get()

Comment: this will only work (probably) if the relationships are correctly defined!